# How to prevent socket from closing when opening JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, sockets

**Edited**

My problem is that i made a simple client-server program that launches a simple JFrame but every time i run it, the socket is closed and server is terminated although i put it in while loop

My server code:

```
public class Server extends Thread{

Socket socket;
public Server(Socket socket)
{
    this.socket = socket;
}

public synchronized void run()
{
    try {  
        String connect = "Connecting Successfully :)";
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF(connect);
        Login l = new Login();
        l.setLocation(350, 250);
        l.setSize(400, 350);
        l.setTitle("Inventory Management System");
        l.setResizable(false);
        l.setVisible(true);
        out.writeObject(l);
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IOException2: " + ex.getMessage() ,"Fatal Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException{

    int i = 0;
    ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(5000);
    while(i == 0)
    {
        Socket ss = s1.accept(); 
        new Server(ss).start();
    }
}
}
```

My client code:

```
    public class Client{

    public static void main(String argv[])
    {

    try{
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost",5000);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    String connect = in.readUTF();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, connect, "Server Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    Login l = (Login)in.readObject();

    //in.close();

    } catch(ConnectException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to connect to the server.", "Connection Failed", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch(IOException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IOException: " + e.getMessage(), "Fatal Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ClassNotFoundException: " + ex.getMessage(), "Fatal Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    finally{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this , "Warining", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
}
}
```

How to fix this please?

Comment: What do you mean by "gui page"?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I mean gui class contains graphics, tables,buttons .. etc.... are you serious of that question ???

Comment: Serious? -- of course I am. You look to be using Swing, and there's no such formal concept of "gui page" in Swing. If you are actually transmitting GUI components via your socket, then that is not something that is typically done and in fact is something that I would strongly advice you not to do. Much better would be to transmit model data over the socket than GUI components as this allows you to transmit data that can be safely serialized if need be, and that is a much smaller amount of data.

Comment: Also, I am finding it difficult to determine how your code above correlates with the code you're describing and the problem that you're describing. You'll likely need to post more code, preferably a [mcve], and more detail about your problems.

Comment: Well, you haven't mentioned or used a tag for which GUI you are using. AWT? Swing? JavaFX? Then you give us code that doesn't allow us to reproduce your problem. You should post a [mcve] instead. I'm guessing you set your frame incorrectly, but I can't say for sure, because you have not posted that part.

Comment: My apologize sir, so please look again at my code ... is what iam doing here is transferring gui components via sockets ... and you say this is not correct ??

Comment: I request from the server to launch gui page that contains some data.

Comment: `"is what iam doing here is transferring gui components via sockets"` -- No. Your code shows you transmitting Strings from the client only. I see no transmission of GUI components in the code above, and again, i do not recommend that you try to do that. But first, please try to greatly improve this question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels post edited, check again please :)

Comment: You've got while true loops running in your server, and that would cause the GUI's event thread to halt, making it not function. You need to do the long-running code in a background thread.

Comment: *"Program close while transferring from gui page to another?"*  My 'best guess' is that the GUIs are frames that declare `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.  But 'guess' is all I can do short of you posting an actual MCVE rather than these uncompilable code snippets.  (Voted to close.)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels check edit?

Comment: You still want to create and post a *valid* [mcve] -- yours is not since we cannot run nor test it. Please read the link. Also similar helpful information can be found at the [sscce](http://sscce.org) link.

Comment: More than this ?? .. this example just launching a frame .. no more than this .. the client code is 4 lines only inside `try` and the server is like this.

Comment: Please read the links as they will explain all, including why this is not sufficient. Seriously.

Comment: I swear i did .. please check it yourself. just copy-paste and run .. just create a jframe named `Login` and leave it empty ....

Comment: Your client isn't even a valid class yet -- how can I run it???? And your code should create any and all JFrames for the test. It should contain all that is needed. Again, **please** read the links.

Comment: Edited ... check again ... create JFrame using any editor... name it Login ... then copy paste and run.

Comment: Note that your "Server" class is not a true Server class. Rather it's a "helper" class to handle the temporary Socket created by calling `accept()` on the ServerSocket.

Answer (score 2):

Sockets don't close spontaneously. *You* are closing the socket. Here:

```
out.close();
```

Closing the input or output stream of a socket closes the socket.

Comment: But that doesn't close the ServerSocket, just the plain Socket created through the `accept()` call. So maybe I'm missing something, but this shouldn't shut down the ServerSocket. 1+ though.

Comment: I tried this sir and not working ... the socket is still closing ... i remove this and the same problem still existing

Comment: @PJA I see no evidence that the `ServerSocket` is being closed, or that the server is exiting. Is there an exception you haven't told us about?

Comment: When i close JFrame ... the server is exiting ... that's happening whenever i tried this ... so for that reason i am asking question. i am handling all expected exceptions on my code. if you think that there is another exception i forget please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

> I have button when i clicked it should pass me to another gui page.

Your client code:

```
// connect socket
Socket ss = new Socket("localhost", 4000);

// create PrintStream from socket's output stream
// for **one way communication** from client to server only
PrintStream pr = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream(), true);

// push two Strings through socket
pr.println("Supplier Orders");
pr.println(Supplier.username);

// close GUI and possibly close program.
this.dispose();
```

So this code appears to send 2 Strings to the server and then tries to exit.

---

Also:
In your server, your totally tying up the current thread with your while true loop, and if this is on the GUI event thread, the GUI will "freeze". You should run all long-running code, or thread-halting code from within a background thread so that it does not hamper the GUI's event thread.

If still stuck, then again, create and post your [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

**Edit**
I tried to make an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your code, and this is what I get:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class HisSocket {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Server.main(args);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Client.main(args);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

class Server extends Thread {

    Socket socket;

    public Server(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            String connect = "Connecting Successfully :)";
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF(connect);
            Login l = new Login();
            l.setLocation(350, 250);
            l.setSize(400, 350);
            l.setTitle("Inventory Management System");
            l.setResizable(false);
            l.setVisible(true);
            out.writeObject(l);
            out.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IOException2: " + ex.getMessage(), "Fatal Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {

        int i = 0;
        ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(5000);
        while (i == 0) {
            Socket ss = s1.accept();
            new Server(ss).start();
        }
    }
}

class Login extends JFrame {
    public Login() {
        super("Login");
        // setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new JLabel("Login JFrame", SwingConstants.CENTER));
    }
}

class Client {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            String connect = in.readUTF();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, connect, "Server Success",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            Login l = (Login) in.readObject();

            // in.close();

        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to connect to the server.",
                    "Connection Failed", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IOException: " + e.getMessage(), "Fatal Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ClassNotFoundException: " + ex.getMessage(),
                    "Fatal Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } finally {
            // !! I couldn't use this because this doesn't exist in a static context
            // and so your code wouldn't compile.
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this, "Warining",
            // JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "client this", "Warining",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Tell me what I'm supposed to be experiencing.

Comment: iam still stuck, but anyway i have another problem ... when my clients closed running ... the server also closed running while iam designing it in while loop to keep running ... can you explain how to fix this please ?

Comment: Your server is running a GUI? and the GUI exits? Again, consider working on creating you [mcve] so we can understand your code and problems.

Comment: ok gui exits, but why server is exiting ????? it is put in an infinite while loop .. what is the thing that cause while loop to get out ?? value of `i` is still 0

Comment: @PJA: without runnable code, it's very very hard to say. Again, please look at the [mcve] specification.

Comment: @PJA: also -- how are you handling exceptions in your server?

Comment: maybe no, what type of exceptions i can handle ?? .. i am using netbeans 8.1 IDE editor ... so if there is any exception .. IDE will give error until i handle this exception ... but for now only IOException on client.

Comment: I check your solution ... the same problem exists ... the JFrame is launched but the socket is closed .... please try it again ... when you close the JFrame the server is stop working.

Comment: @PJA: try it again after commenting out this line: `// setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`. also how do you know that the server has stopped working?

Comment: When you close JFrame ... the server will exit automatically ... this is the problem iam asking about. anyway i tried your code and works fine :) .... thanks a lot .... but this is not fixing the full problem ... I have created a JFrame using netbeans IDE ... this line of code doesn't exists so i cannot comment it. you comment this because you knew before that socket is closing so when commenting it will disapear because the socket stopped it from the beginning  but if the socket was working good so if you comment this line and click x ... the window will not closed. ... anyway thanks a lot :)

Comment: This problem sounds some strange ... anyway i appreciate all your efforts with me ... if you could find a nice tutorial for fixing this problem .. i will appreciate this ... please post it in StackOverflow to check it :) .. thanks again sir :)

Comment: @PJA: I still think that you have a non-problem. Let me see if I can prove it to you, but this will take some work.

Comment: OK sir, take your time and when you finish just post your solution in a tutorial and post a tag of my account to check it ... good luck :)